# Voltage drop drain to source n mosfet

Tags: voltage, source

Following simple test circuits online I hooked up a n-mosfet with V+ being 12 volts and the gate on a 20k pot from V+ to ground. There is a large voltage drop, even open source (to vom only) and even with the gate and drain both connected to V+.
For example with V+ 12v to gate and drain and a 15 ohm load from source to ground there is a 4.4 volt drop from drain to source. If a 5 ohm load at 17.8V (current is about 3A) i get a 5.6 volt drop.
Since the resistance from drain to source is very low (IRFZ44N) I would expect little drop which is what the online circuits show hooked up this way, and their reported output varies from V+ to 0. So why am I getting these large voltage drops? The IRFP250 acts in a similar way. Thanks, Phil

Comment: Hello there and welcome! Everything sounds as expected given the setup; notice that MOSFET on-ness is determined by gate-source voltage, not gate voltage alone (in some kind of absolute sense); this should clear up your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

These voltages will also change with temperature and devices. A MOSFET is  a 'voltage controlled resistor'. The on resistance is controlled by the voltage on the gate referenced from the source on both P and N channel devices. They are high gain and will switch from high resistance to low resistance over a small voltage range. The parameter to check is Vgs (Voltage from  Gate to Source). For a P device the gate voltage needs to be negative in reference to the source and the opposite on N channel devices where the gate has to be positive in reference to the source. You can look at the Vgs graph on a MOSFET and see this.

Answer (score 0):

> *For example with V+ 12v to gate and drain and a 15 ohm load from
> source to ground there is a 4.4 volt drop from drain to source.*

Perfectly normal and reasonable for a source follower circuit.

> *Since the resistance from drain to source is very low (IRFZ44N) I
> would expect little drop which is what the online circuits show hooked
> up this way, and their reported output varies from V+ to 0.*

No, the drain-source resistance won't be very low in a source follower circuit. If you want to show the MOSFET as a switch you must test it with the load resistor in series with the drain and the source connected to ground (common source circuit).

> *So why am I getting these large voltage drops?*

Because you are not using the right circuit.